# incompatible types when assigning to type ‘char *[80]’ from type ‘char **’ error

Tags: c, linux, compiler-errors

When I compile the following line, it gets "incompatible types when assigning to type ‘char *[80]’ from type ‘char **’" error. Both 'nw' and 'source' are sentences (from sentence structure type).
This question is different from others sinces it deals with two dimensional arrays which have not been discussed otherwhere.

```
nw.sentence = source->sentence;
```

The sentence structure type is:

```
typedef struct {
    char *sentence[MAX_LINE_LENGTH];
} sentence;
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that you have the declaration

```
int *x;
```

This means that `x` has type `int *`, in other words is a pointer to an int. In the same logic, the declaration

```
 char *sentence[MAX_LINE_LENGTH];
```

means that every element of `sentence[MAX_LINE_LENGTH]` (which is an array of `MAX_LINE_LENGTH` elements) has type `char *`, in other words is a pointer to a string.

As a conclusion, every element of `char *sentence[MAX_LINE_LENGTH]` points to a string. This is different from the declaration

```
char ** sentence;
```

as the last one is a *pointer to pointer to string.*